# Regular expression to extract a string starts at '=' ends at '\t'

Tags: java, regex

I have a log file with data

```
AgentDevice=WindowsLog
AgentLogFile=Security
PluginVersion=7.2.3.2015120
Message=A privileged service was called.
```

The groups are separated using tabs. So I need to cut the data starting at `=` and ending `\t`

I tried this one `PluginVersion=([\w.]*)\w` but it cuts the last symbol and in addition doesn't work with data like this:

`Message=A privileged service was called.`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
PluginVersion=([^\t]*)
```

That is a negative character class.  It will match all the non `\t`, effectively up to the next `\t` or the end if there are no more `\t`